# Getting all Substrings between two expressions using regexs pattern (JAVA)

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

I have the following string (str):

```
 String  str="${name}/${family}/${child}/${fname}"
```

what regex pattern do I use in java to get all substrings between "${" and "}" and save them in an arraylist ,
so the result will be an array list with the following values: "name", "family", "child", "fname"

Comment: The regex matchers don't return arrays of stuff like this.  You might be able to come up with a complex regex that you can use with `split()`, but it's not worth it.  Write a regex to find _one_ substring, then use the `find()` method in a loop and build an `ArrayList`.  Simple, readable, less error-prone.

Comment: @ajb I assumed the intent was to loop. I don't see why you inferred otherwise.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("[\\$\\{\\}]", "").split("/")));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hey that's cheating! :)

Comment: can you please show me a sample code of the regex pattern to use and how can I use it to loop through the string.

Comment: @shmosel Because I've seen a lot of similar questions where someone wants to execute a matcher once and get an array in return.  I could have been wrong here.

Comment: Use this regex: `"\\$\\{(.*?)\\}"`.  Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html to see how to use a matcher in a loop.  You can use `matcher.group(1)` to retrieve the "capture group", which will be the characters between `{` and `}`.

Comment: You have to K.I.S.S. every time right @ElliottFrisch I lol so hard at your solution and the comment of shmosel xD amazingly simple and great at same time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could *compile* a `Pattern` with `"\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}"` and then loop to build a `List` like,

```
String str = "${name}/${family}/${child}/${fname}";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
while (mat.find()) {
    al.add(mat.group(1));
}
System.out.println(al);
```

**or**, like I said in my comment, just one line like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("[\\$\\{\\}]‌​", "").split("/")));
```

Comment: I'm sad that I can upvote this only one time. That *or* solution :)